# Should all tabs in a data table necessarily contain the same column names?

Tags: tables, info-visualisation, information-architecture, tabs

For example we have these tabs for a data table:

[image]

Basically, All tab will display Drafts, Pending and Processed. However, individually, Drafts / Pending / Processed may have columns that the others do not have. E.g. Processed will have another column called "Processed Date".

Will it be confusing for the user if all of a sudden, Processed tab has a column that is not in the All / Draft / Pending tab? Since that column is not relevant to those tabs.

Comment: Are the Status column possible values Draft/Pending/Processed? Does it appear in the other tabs?

Answer (score 1):

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJfpTH.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>
Radio button will solve the problem instead of having tab structure. Default view would be all. User can switch the options to view specific status option.
You can have one more column in table wherein the status would be displayed.

In addition to this are the table header same across all tabs i.e (Order no.,order date etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

If it is only about a column where you indicate the Pending/Draft/Processed date think about:

- including a relevant column that can be common and useful for all tabs, maybe last modification date
- include the date also in the Status field (considering its value is Pending/Draft/Processed) so the column doesn't become useless when you are in one of those tabs

If there are a number of columns to be added unrelated with the others tabs, then I would suggest **keeping the common columns in the same place and altogether**.  Let's say on the left side and the ones that will appear depending on the state on the right side.